# Vue components in app no longer propogates state changes to computed methods after refactoring of my VUEX store

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I refactored my Vuex store from using Promises, to using asyns/await style. After applying that change, somehow my computed methods are no longer "dynamic".

Let me give an example.

```
    /// old approach
    getCurrentUser({commit}) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        usersService.current()
        .then(
            user => { 
                commit('setUserId', user.id)
                User.insert({data: user})
                resolve(user)
            },
            error => reject(error)
       )
      })

    /// new approach
    async getCurrentUser({ dispatch, commit }) {
      const response = await handleApiAction({
        dispatch,
        record: false,
        action: () => usersService.current(),
        modelClass: User,
      });
      return commit('setUserId', response.id)
```

The problem occurs in my c omponent, where I try to access the User ID, which is stored in a state variable `state.current_user.id`

```
  // code in my component that depends on above service API calls

  computed: {
    notifications() {
      return Notification.query()
        .where('target_type','User')
        .where('target_id', this.current_user_id)
        .orderBy('created_at', 'desc').get()
    },
    current_user_id() {
      return his.$store.state.users.current_user.id
    }
```

Somehow the Notifications never get loaded, as the computed method `current_user_id` doesn't seem to return a value. When I inspect my Vue store (via Chrome plugin), I do see that the value gets properly set, only somehow the computed method isn't informed when the update is received in the async/await scenario. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: "old" and "new" differ a lot, it's unknown what handleApiAction is and whether it's correctly implemented.  `return his` - is this a typo? If it was lost when you wrote code for the questino this means that original code can differ in some way. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: I'ds love to give MCVE, but weird thing is that if I isolate the code, it seems to work as expected. But somehow with these service calls involved, it somehow stops event propogation. I'm not sure how to give full MCVE as there's many elements involved (nested components / VUEX store with service etc.)

Comment: That's not weird at all, asking the correct question is half the work. Any way, besides the typo there's nothing fundamentally wrong in these snippets, it's about other changes in code that could happen to make it work incorrectly